# Кот-баюн: от слова "баюкать" или "баять"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Персонаж русской мифологии Кот-баюн, интересно, от какого слова или даже не слова, а понятия образовалось его имя: баюкать или баять? И, кстати, интересно, родственны ли оба эти слова?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

От "баять". Это и по структуре слова понятно - и по роли данного фольклорного персонажа. 
Баять - говорить, рассказывать (часто - с оттенком уважительности, высокой оценки самого действа). Баюн, тот кто много и красиво говорит. 
А вот что касается родственности... Не уверен до конца, а проверит сейчас технически не могу, но очень похоже, что они действительно родственны. Хотя, очевидно, что "баюкать" - от "бай-бай", "баю-бай". Вопрос только в том, связано ли это детское "колыбельное" слово с "баять". Я думаю, что да, отсюда и предположение о родственноти.

Answer (score 1):

> Баюн, тот кто много и красиво говорит.

Такого еще краснобаем называют.

Comment: Да. Но "баюн", видимо, более древнее.